# How to nest a submenu in mobile navigation hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to nest a submenu in a main menu for a mobile navigation hamburger menu. Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Right now, my submenus are appearing over my other menus and not embedding inside. I cannot figure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a link to the [codepen.io pin](https://codepen.io/webdevxd/pen/oNdOjqY).

Here is the same code in codepen.io:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.main-navigation-bar {
  height: 94px;
  background-color: #00000000;
  display: flex;
}

.section-1 {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.logo-box {
  width: 208px;
  height: 48px;
  
}




.section-2 {
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
 
}

.main-nav li{
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 700;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-style: normal;
   text-decoration: none;
   line-height: 24px;
   letter-spacing: .75px;
  color: #1e1e1e;
}

.main-nav li:hover {
  color: #1e1e1e75;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .4s;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(calc(-50%));
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-top: 10px;
 
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu {
  list-style-type:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgb(30 30 30 / 25%) !important;
  z-index: 3px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  
}


.sub-menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 24px 32px !important;
  width: 100%;
  
}

.sub-menu li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item1 {
  border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}


.product {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  color: #1e1e1e;
}


.tagline {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: .44px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #1e1e1e;
}


.g4-sub-tabs {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0px; 
}

.g4-sub-tabs li {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.li-sub-tab {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

#check, .open-menu, .close-menu {
    display: none;
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  .open-menu, .close-menu {
    position: absolute;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  
  .open-menu {
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  
  .close-menu {
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
  }
  
  #check {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .main-navigation-bar {
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}

.section-2 {
  width: 100%;
}
  
  .mobile-menu {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  
  
  .mobile-menu li {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  
  
  .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(calc(0%));
  max-width: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
 
}

.sub-menu {
  list-style-type:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgb(30 30 30 / 25%) !important;
  z-index: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  
}


.sub-menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 24px 32px !important;
  width: 100%;
  
}
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<header>
  <div class="main-navigation-bar">
    <div class="section-1">
      <div class="logo-box">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <div class="section-2">
      <nav>
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <span class="mobile-menu">
          <span class="dropdown">
          <li>Products
          <span class="sub-arrow">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </span></span>
            <span class="dropdown-content">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="item1 "><a href="#"><span class="product">1A</span><p class="tagline">Lorem ipsum solor sal</p></a>
                <ul class="g4-sub-tabs">
                  <li>&#8226;<span class="li-sub-tab">Link</span></li>
                  <li>&#8226;<span class="li-sub-tab">Link</span></li><li>&#8226;<span class="li-sub-tab">Link</span></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li class"item2"><span class="product">1B</span><p class="tagline">lorem ipsum dolor sal</p></li>
            </ul>
            </span>
          </li>
          <li>Resources</li>
          <li>Company</li>
          <li>Careers</li>
          <li>Contact Us</li>
        <label for="check" class="close-menu"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
          </span>
        <label for="check" class="open-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the CSS `display` rule and toggle `none`.

```js
if (document.getElementById("btn")) {
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
        toggleDisplay(evt);
    });
}

function toggleDisplay(evt){
    document.getElementById("first").classList.toggle("hidden"); 
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="main-navigation-bar">
    <button id="btn">toggle me</button>
    <div class="section-1">
      <div class="logo-box">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-2">
      <nav>
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <span class="mobile-menu">
          <span class="dropdown">
          <li>Products
          <span class="sub-arrow">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </span></span>
            <span class="dropdown-content">
            <ul class="hidden" id="first">
              <li class="item1 "><a href="#"><span class="product">1A</span><p class="tagline">Lorem ipsum solor sal</p></a>
                <ul class="g4-sub-tabs">
                  <li>&#8226;<span class="li-sub-tab">Link</span></li>
                  <li>&#8226;<span class="li-sub-tab">Link</span></li><li>&#8226;<span class="li-sub-tab">Link</span></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li class"item2"><span class="product">1B</span><p class="tagline">lorem ipsum dolor sal</p></li>
            </ul>
            </span>
          </li>
          <li>Resources</li>
          <li>Company</li>
          <li>Careers</li>
          <li>Contact Us</li>
        <label for="check" class="close-menu"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
          </span>
        <label for="check" class="open-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```